# Euclidean and rectilinear distance and nonlinearity

Tags: geometry, linear-programming

Can some one please explain why Euclidean distance and rectilinear distance make a problem nonlinear?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, a linear function of two variables would be something like:
$f(x,y) = A*x + B*y + C$
Rectilinear and Euclidean distances are not like that. They involve nonlinear stuff like absolute value and square roots.